# How to resolve this OAuth authorization error( Error 400: invalid request )?

Tags: firebase, react-native, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, expo

Alright. I'll cut to the chase and won't waste your time.

There's an expo *bare-workflow* app to which, the authentication with expo-sessions and firebase has to be added. Google is the provider that's needed to be used. But the app has been slapping me with this error for quite a sometime now.

Here's the code:

```js
const AuthContext = createContext({});

const config = {
  clientId:
    "380XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  redirectUri:
    "com.newauth.newauth://newauth-XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler",
  // redirectUri: "https://newauth-XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/auth/handler",
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<String>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<String>();
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<String>();
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest(config);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMessage(JSON.stringify(response));
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      setAccessToken(response?.authentication?.accessToken);
    }
    console.log(
      "response is ==> ",
      response,
      "and is of type ==> ",
      response?.type
    );
    console.log("message: ", message);
    console.log("request: ", request);
    console.log("response: ", response);
    console.log("promptAsync: ", promptAsync);
  }, [response]);

  async function signInWithGoogle() {
    console.log("@signInWithGoogle");

    WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

    try {
      console.log("At try block");

      promptAsync({ useProxy: false, showInRecents: true });
      // Google.useAuthRequest(config, discovery);

      console.log("request: ", JSON.stringify(request));
      console.log("response: ", JSON.stringify(response));
      console.log("response type: ", response?.type);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: null,
        signInWithGoogle,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

This ends up slamming me with this error[image]

Do you know a way out of this?

Thanks and have a fantastic weekend!